How to remove a file which name seems to be "." on an SMB share?
Overview
Incorrect specification of an argument in a commandline tool (details below) has led to the creation of a file literally named ".". I have already found out that directly trying to delete in Finder will trigger deletion of all content in the containing folder (fortunately this is a temporary folder), but still not the "." file itself. Moreover, no folders containing this file can be successfully deleted, neither with Finder nor from bash/zsh shell.
How can one actually delete (or rename) such a file?

Attempts to delete from zsh
For example:
mytmp % ls -hal
total 65
drwx------  1 user  staff    16K Aug 21 11:20 .
-rwx------  1 user  staff     0B Aug 21 09:51 .
drwx------  1 user  staff    16K Aug 16 16:30 ..

mytmp % ls -aB
.   .   ..

mytmp % rm -rf '.'                   
rm: "." and ".." may not be removed

mytmp % cd ..

scratch % rm -rf mytmp
rm: mytmp: Permission denied

scratch % sudo rm -rf mytmp
rm: mytmp: Permission denied

I've also tried variations without -r, since really it is the non-directory version that is to be deleted.
I additionally tried the suggestion of @bmike to use the inode. While we can identify the inode, the deletion does not appear to work:
scratch % ls -ila mytmp
total 65
8056451580272514705 drwx------  1 user  staff  16384 Aug 21 11:20 .
8652239633868421122 -rwx------  1 user  staff      0 Aug 21 09:51 .
                  2 drwx------  1 user  staff  16384 Aug 21 11:43 ..

scratch % find mytmp -inum 8652239633868421122 -delete

## no change
scratch % ls -ila mytmp
total 65
8056451580272514705 drwx------  1 user  staff  16384 Aug 21 11:20 .
8652239633868421122 -rwx------  1 user  staff      0 Aug 21 09:51 .
                  2 drwx------  1 user  staff  16384 Aug 21 11:43 ..

Is it really named "."?
@nohillside proposed to delimit the listings with x and y to see if it really is named ".". From bash:
bash-3.2$ for i in .*; do echo x${i}y; done
x.y
x.y
x..y

Appears so.
@fd0 suggested printing non-printing characters with cat -vet. From bash:
bash-3.2$ ls -1a | cat -vet
.$
.$
..$

Again, seems identically named.
@nohillside Suggested running a Python server from the directory and display its directory listing:

Is "." really that dot?
We can dump octal to see it is the same as the dot representing "this directory":
bash-3.2$ ls -a | od -cb
0000000    .  \n   .  \n   .   .  \n                                    
          056 012 056 012 056 056 012                                    
0000007

Also, the above-reported behavior of Finder should indicate that it is interpreted as that dot.

Additional Background
The folder is on a network Volume, format SMB (OS X).
The tool that resulted in this was haplogrep, a Java-based CLI. One can install it through Conda via
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda haplogrep

The subcommand used was haplogrep classify, which has the following options:
mytmp % haplogrep classify

mtDNA Haplogroup Classifiction v2.4.0
https://github.com/seppinho/haplogrep-cmd
(c) Sebastian Schönherr, Hansi Weissensteiner, Lukas Forer, Dominic Pacher
sebastian.schoenherr@i-med.ac.at

[classify]
Missing required options: '--input=<in>', '--output=<out>', '--format=<format>'
Usage: haplogrep classify [--chip] [--extend-report] [--rsrs]
                          [--skip-alignment-rules] [--write-fasta]
                          [--write-fasta-msa] --format=<format>
                          [--hetLevel=<hetLevel>] [--hits=<hits>] --in=<in>
                          [--lineage=<lineage>] [--metric=<metric>] --out=<out>
                          [--phylotree=<tree>]
      --chip                VCF data from a genotype chip
                              Default: false
      --extend-report       Add flag for a extended final output
                              Default: false
      --format=<format>     Specify input file format: vcf, fasta or hsd
      --hetLevel=<hetLevel> Add heteroplasmies with a level > X from the VCF
                              file to the profile (default: 0.9)
      --hits=<hits>         Calculate best n hits
      --in, --input=<in>    Input VCF, fasta or hsd file
      --lineage=<lineage>   Export lineage information as dot file, \n0=no
                              tree, 1=with SNPs, 2=only structure, no SNPs
      --metric=<metric>     Specifiy other metrics (hamming or jaccard) than
                              default (kulczynski)
      --out, --output=<out> Output file location
      --phylotree=<tree>    Specify phylotree version
      --rsrs                Use RSRS Version
                              Default: false
      --skip-alignment-rules
                            Skip mtDNA nomenclature fixes based on rules for
                              FASTA import
                              Default: false
      --write-fasta         Write results in fasta format
                              Default: false
      --write-fasta-msa     Write multiple sequence alignment (_MSA.fasta)
                              Default: false

I misinterpreted the "Output file location" description of the --out argument as asking for a path, leading me to use --out . and thus resulting in creating a file named ".".
Renaming
The file itself cannot be renamed in Finder or with mv, however, the containing folder can be renamed.

What are ownership and permissions on mytemp?

@nohillside the ownership and permissions on mytmp are what correspond to the first '.' entry in the ls -hal. I.e., I am the owner, with rwx.

@benwiggy TAB completion shows two options: ./ and ../.

With Unicode and other encodings, it might be easier to find the inode of this empty file for  less confusing removal options rather than go deeper into ACL to understand why you’re getting a permission error to remove the parent directory.

@bmike one can clearly see the unique inode, but the find -delete has no effect.

Can you just delete the enclosing folder and start again?

I'm wondering if this is an issue with how directory listings are displayed, by default in Unix based operating systems. I may be misunderstanding things (badly) but here is one explanation: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21778/whats-so-special-about-directories-whose-names-begin-with-a-dot#21867

@SteveChambers This doesn't explain the existence of a file which seems to have the name ..

Can you show us the results of the following command (as text not a screen shot)?   ls -1a | cat -vet | head -n5

Not enough for an answer: I previously had success with Emacs when I created a file with a troublesome name (linux, ext4). Come to think of it, you can try using vim (already installed) to browse the directory.

@TAR86 right, vim is displaying the culprit immediately with vim ..

On which kind of filesystem was created this strange file? Please run:[↵]
_disk=$(df . | sed -n 's,^/dev/\([^ ]*\) .*$,\1,p') ; diskutil info ${_disk} and include it inside of your question.

Note: there are 2 clearly distinct problems here:[↵]

an unusual file name ( which cannot be "." ),[↵]
a directory permission problem.[↵]
Perhaps 2 other ones:[↵]
a damaged volume,[↵]
a bug inside the filesystem.


Might be a stupid question, but did you reboot the system?

@athena it is a network volume (SMB); because this is a mixed (Win/Mac/Linux users) network, I would not expect it is APFS-based.

Ah, that changed things. Can you log into the system providing the share?

@nohillside nope, would have to escalate to IT

Please do, with SMB between your Mac and whatever OS/filesystem is running in the remote system, there are too many things you can‘t control or manipulate.

ls | hexdump -C or whatever hex dump tool you have would be a way to check for characters other than . (ASCII dot 0x2e) and the newline (0x0a) printed by ls.  And/or dtrace or truss or whatever macOS uses these days on the ls process to see its getdents system call actually returning this name.

@bmike while I agree that the SMB has turned out to be a crucial factor, I question the judgement to qualify the title after several users have answered without knowing that. That is, the non-SMB-specific answers could be useful for future visitors who are not in a SMB context (if even possible), whereas changing the title to be about SMB might deter them.

The shell script with for i in .*; do echo x${i}y; done should be fixed with " to protect ${i}: "${i}". Otherwise, a space, backspace, tab, return… will silently be swallowed by the shell.

Could you add this key information ( the FS is a remote one from an SMB server ) at the top of your question, and moreover add the OS on which is running your SMB server. This could avoid many too fast answers. And the level of problem might be totally different depending on the OS implementing the SMB protocol.

To avoid missing key details, could you run ls -@aBelO in mytmp?

When you write "format SMB (OS X)" do you mean the SMB server is running on macOS?

This case looks pretty near from this older one: https://superuser.com/questions/458995/files-folders-get-weird-names-and-become-inaccessible-on-samba-share . @merv : please forward to the sysadmin in charge of your SMB server.[↵]I'd bet a beer you can reproduce the problem at will with : >'. ' .

This other case too: https://serverfault.com/questions/124611/special-characters-in-samba-filenames .

Maybe it isn't that dot - if you copy-and-paste the filename into a delete command does it work?

@AndrewMorton it is that dot. Perhaps the reported behavior of Finder is underappreciated: attempting to delete the "file" (Command + delete) results in deleting all other contents in the folder. I interpret that as rather clear evidence that Finder interprets it as the same dot that under normal circumstances refers to the folder itself.

As this is in a SMB mounted drive, the troublesome file needs to be removed in the source system (the server sharing the drive). The file is for sure named strangely for the SMB protocol to render it as ., but there is no way to use SMB to actually delete the file.

Since the plain file creation was done in user mode on the client side ( SMB ), the unlink should be accessible the same way from the client. I continue to be sure the file name is not ".". This is not possible on any UNIX FS.

@athena we don‘t know the filesystem used on the SMB server. We also don‘t know whatever transformation the SMB layer does to convert the filename known to the server into the lone „.“ we see. All we know is that the script the OP run created a file via SMB which on the way back gets represented as „.“ and can not be deleted via SMB.

I‘m close to creating a new share on the NAS to test this, but it may need NTFS on the server.

This is the only sane answer. And if the server hosting the share is Windows you will need PowerShell  (or a 3rd party file-manager) to be able to delete (or rename to something sane) the file. Windows own File Explorer will not handle this file it the name really consists of a single dot. It has a nasty tendency to balk at stuff it doesn't like/understand and is especially problematic at handling files whose name ends with a dot (and is even worse at dealing with folders whose name ends in a dot).

I'm crashing this party. The essential bit of information here seems to be that the following command fails with a permissions error, even though there is no obvious reason why it should:
rm -rf mytmp

I think this means that the 'haplogrep' executable has somehow managed to create a file with an illegal name, thereby corrupting the volume directory. If that's the case, no amount of beating your head against the wall in the shell or the Finder will get rid of it. You should therefore run 'First Aid' on the volume in Disk Utility and hope for the best. Failing that, you may actually have to erase the volume and restore everything else from a backup.
Update: This answer was posted before it was disclosed that the volume in question is a network share. The solution is not applicable.

If we indeed don‘t find a way to get rid of the troublesome file, simply moving mytmp out of the way is probably enough.

@Linc D. sorry no party crash. Unless Apple really  deeply damaged the internal of Unix filesystem with APFS, it is not possible to create a file or directory named exactly ".".

And yet, here we are.

Have to agree with @nohillside - since I can rename this undeletable folder, it seems a better workaround to rename it into obsolescence (e.g., .nothing-to-see-here). Also, I unfortunately don't have root perms on the volume, so practically the wipe is not possible. All that said, still a valuable contribution to the discussion (+1).

@merv : Since you aren't an admin on this system, I advise you to report the problem to your admin, and without telling him the name is "." to avoid to push him on false track, and to avoid to stay with an unanalysed and never fixed problem. vim . is simple enough to show you the name is not ".".

Disk Utility won't be accessible to a non admin user.[↵]
If the corruption of the FS is a path to investigate ( which I am not at all convinced ) then it has to be run on the server, since this is a remote FS through SMB.

It is most likely not called . because that is a reserved name. If these are the only three directory entries, try rm -i .* and skip ...

Sharp. File could be name . . That's a dot with a trailing space. Could also be a dot followed by non-printable character

Yields: zsh: no matches found: .*. Similar with "*.*" for the zsh completion.

@merv Ah, zsh. Can you start bash and try again?

With bash, yields: rm: "." and ".." may not be removed

cd ..; rm mytemp/.* might work as well.

@merv did you use the -i option?

Yes, used the -i option; also, same with rm mytmp/.* (with or without -i).

But, at the beginning, on the client side a file creation was initiated with open(2) with a first arg of "." which should have failed on EEXIST before resolving which server to call behind the VFS layer. Then on any Unixes, a file named . cannot be created whichever the server is. Then this answer stands true.

@athene we don‘t know whether „.“ was passed to open(). If it would, it should have failed immediately.

You may be looking at something with UTF-8 encoding - there are more than one dot characters in the world. I'm not an OSX user, but maybve you can do something like this from linux:
# ls -al | od -c
0000000   t   o   t   a   l       6   0  \n   -   r   w   -   r   -   -
0000020   r   -   -       1       r   o   o   t       r   o   o   t    
0000040       1   3   9   1       A   u   g       2   3       1   2   :
0000060   0   1       c   a   .   c   r   t  \n   -   r   w   -   -   -
0000100   -   -   -   -       1       r   o   o   t       r   o   o   t
0000120           1   8   7   4       A   u   g       2   3       1   2
0000140   :   0   1       c   a   .   k   e   y  \n   -   r   w   -   r
0000160   -   -   r   -   -       1       r   o   o   t       r   o   o
0000200   t                   4   1       A   u   g       2   3       1
0000220   2   :   0   1       c   a   .   s   r   l  \n   d   r   w   x
0000240   r   -   x   r   -   x       2       r   o   o   t       r   o
0000260   o   t           4   0   9   6       N   o   v       1   1    
0000300       2   0   2   3       c   l   i   e   n   t   /  \n   -   r
0000320   w   -   r   -   -   r   -   -       1       r   o   o   t    
0000340   r   o   o   t               4   2   4       A   u   g       2
0000360   3       1   2   :   0   1       d   h   2   0   4   8   .   p
0000400   e   m  \n   d   r   w   x   r   -   x   r   -   x       2    
0000420   r   o   o   t       r   o   o   t           4   0   9   6    
0000440   N   o   v       1   1           2   0   2   3       s   e   r
0000460   v   e   r   /  \n   -   r   w   -   r   -   -   r   -   -    
0000500   1       r   o   o   t       r   o   o   t               5   9
0000520   9       A   u   g       2   3       1   3   :   5   0       s
0000540   e   r   v   e   r   .   c   o   n   f  \n   -   r   w   -   r
0000560   -   -   r   -   -       1       r   o   o   t       r   o   o
0000600   t       1   0   8   8   2       A   u   g       2   3       1
0000620   1   :   5   8       s   e   r   v   e   r   .   c   o   n   f
0000640   .   b   k  \n   -   r   w   -   r   -   -   r   -   -       1
0000660       r   o   o   t       r   o   o   t           1   2   6   9
0000700       A   u   g       2   3       1   2   :   0   1       s   e
0000720   r   v   e   r   .   c   r   t  \n   -   r   w   -   r   -   -
0000740   r   -   -       1       r   o   o   t       r   o   o   t    
0000760       1   0   6   6       A   u   g       2   3       1   2   :
0001000   0   1       s   e   r   v   e   r   .   c   s   r  \n   -   r
0001020   w   -   -   -   -   -   -   -       1       r   o   o   t    
0001040   r   o   o   t           1   7   0   4       A   u   g       2
0001060   3       1   2   :   0   1       s   e   r   v   e   r   .   k
0001100   e   y  \n   -   r   w   -   -   -   -   -   -   -       1    
0001120   r   o   o   t       r   o   o   t               6   3   6    
0001140   A   u   g       2   3       1   2   :   0   1       t   a   .
0001160   k   e   y  \n   -   r   w   x   r   -   x   r   -   x       1
0001200       r   o   o   t       r   o   o   t           1   4   6   8
0001220       N   o   v       1   1           2   0   2   3       u   p
0001240   d   a   t   e   -   r   e   s   o   l   v   -   c   o   n   f
0001260  \n
0001261

od -c shows your output as normal characters, if they are printable, or escape codes otherwise; alternatively, od -x will show a hex-dump.

od -cb (octal) gave the clearest output - indeed it is that dot and nothing more.

Did you perhaps create the file with a GUI tool, I wonder? I have sometimes found that files can get odd names that wouldn't necessarily have been possible from the command line. If so, then you should be able to do something - rename or delete it - with such a tool.

Since the only remaining problematic file is a plain file
just enter:
find . -name "*" -type f -exec echo "{}" \; | od -cx

You will see the string of characters before or following the . in this file name within the output of od as character and hexa.
For example a space, a newline, a return, a tab, a bell, a backspace ( worse ? ). I would bet on a meta-space ( my left thumb like to
make me this stupid joke ).
Just out of curiosity, tell us what was this ( these ) non visible
character :).
Then use the same trick to remove it:
find . -name "*" -type f -exec rm "{}" \;

I finally got a simpler solution:
vi .

go to the line where is the dirty file, if you cannot see anything strange hit :l to see space, return or any other strange character. Then hit D to delete it, confirm with a y, quit with :q, smile.

AFAICT, find is not discovering the file. Using echo .* picks up . . ... As for vi ., it lists the three as ../, ./, and ./, which 1) doesn't give me any indication what is what and 2) suggests the file is interpreted as a directory.

echo .* isn't sufficient to protect evaluation of $IFS and other characters. Please use only _dirty=$(echo .*) ; echo \""${_dirty}"\"

In vi the 2 "." looking entry couldn't be the same: th edirectory one should end with a / and the file one eventually with other characters you can only see with the help of :l as indicated in my answer.

@merv : "find is not..." do you mean the exact command I suggested ( with all the " ) just returned nothing.

@merv : there was a syntax error in my find command. I typed it from memory. Sorry.

@merv, could you try this new version of find command. I tested it on all imaginable dirty names which the Finder cannot see, and are hard to manage with the shell ( whichever its religion ). This command should output one line.

No, find . -name "*" -type f does not find it.
